# Mitigating slowdown in Visual Studio during debugging when large number of exceptions being thrown and caught

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am requesting a page consuming a 3rd-party dll that has some code like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= maxBound; ++i)
{
    try
    {
       return DoDangerousThing();
    }
    catch
    {
       return SafeValue;
    }
}
```

This code runs well enough if I'm not debugging, but when I do debug, this bit ends up taking so long eventually a ThreadAbortException terminates the thread which allows the request to complete. I'm assuming it's running much slower because Visual Studio has hooks for figuring out when an exception is thrown, logging exceptions to Output, etc.

Is there any way I can configure Visual Studio to not worry about exceptions so much, especially caught/handled ones?

Comment: You're trying to debug something in your own code right? Not a part of their third party library?

Comment: @DrewJordan Correct. I did try turning Just My Code on but I didn't really notice an improvement, just the absence of the Output logging.

Comment: Huh, One other thing you can try is Project > Properties > Build > Optimize Code, but be aware you can't count on breakpoints when debugging with it turned on

Comment: @DrewJordan Yeah, I just may end up doing that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. I am sure this should help. Go to

```
Visual Studio -> Debug Menu -> Exceptions (or Ctl + Alt + E)
```

[image]

Comment: No, the debugger is not breaking on the exception.

Comment: Well, that's what u said you want " Visual Studio to not worry about exceptions so much, especially caught/handled ones" ??

Comment: I am talking about latency due to handled exceptions. The debugger is (correctly) not breaking on these exceptions. Debugger settings that control whether the debugger breaks on unhandled exceptions do not pertain to my situation.

Comment: Okies, I guess I misunderstood the situation. going through your question again.